# Zend framework 2, проблема с View Helper

Tags: php, zend-framework-2

Когда пытаюсь отобразить форму, это `$form->prepare();` должно отобразить

```
<form name="upload-form" id="upload-form" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="image-file">Avatar Image Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="image-file" id="image-file">
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Но у меня отображает

```
<form name="upload-form" id="upload-form" method="post">
    <div class="form-element">
        <label for="image-file">Avatar Image Upload</label>
        <input type="file" name="image-file" id="image-file">
    </div>

    <button>Submit</button>
</form>
```

Почему то не отображает enctype? Когда не указываю в ручную `$this->setAttribute('enctype', 'multipart/form-data')` , у меня не работает загрузка файлов, за то в таблицу (БД) вносится имя файла. Когда указываю кодировку, у меня не заносится имя файла в таблицу (Column '...' cannot be null), но за то загружается файл на "сервер"

Comment: А можно увидеть класс формы? В официальной документации пишут, что enctype будет добавлен в форму АВТОМАТИЧЕСКИ если там есть FileFileld

Comment: Да переделал немного. Upload файла не работает

Comment: Так можно сам класс формы посмотреть?)